# How make two model‘s block with same structure share weight？

Tags: pytorch

There two model for example class model1(nn.Module) and class model2(nn.Module).
Encoder block is in the two model with same structure.
So how make two model's encoder block share weight?

Make two model's encoder block share weight.

For example:

```
class Model1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels=3):
        super().__init__()

        # shared weight in encoder
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(n_channels, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        return 

class Model2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels=3):
        super().__init__()

        # shared weight in encoder
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(n_channels, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        return
```

How can I make the encoder block in Model1 and Model2 share weight? (The encoder block must be in different modules.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of encoder layers in `model1` and `model2` should be same.

here's a simple model

```
class Model(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, n_channels=3):
    super().__init__()

    # shared weight in encoder
    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(n_channels, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    )

    self.head1 = nn.Conv2d(64, 10, kernel_size=3, padding=1) # task 1
    self.head2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 20, kernel_size=3, padding=1) # task 2
    

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.encoder(x)

    out1 = self.head1(x)    # pass through same input
    out2 = self.head2(x)    # pass through same input

    return
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I add one requre: the encoder block must be in different modules when I use them in GAN training. Then how can I make the encoder block share weight?

Comment: @Sora
Conversely, why there needs different 2 model? Since the member variables in the different class are pointing different address, it can't be logically same. Simply think that gradients of 2 different path are not same. There would be an another solution that do not requiring 2 models.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I try to define a function to make another module use the same encoder block.